# Can you specify which resource folder an Android device uses?

Tags: android, android-layout

I just got the new Nexus 7 which pulls images from the drawable-xhdpi folder because it is 1920x1200.  The Nexus 10 also pulls from the drawable-xhdpi folder.  The same image looks too big on the Nexus 7 as a result (too big by 150% to be exact).  Is there any way to specify a resourse (drawable) folder to use for a specific device?

It sounds like I should not be trying to over-ride the default drawable buckets since there are so many screen sizes and it could hinder me when I attempt to support even more devices.  So then what is the best way to handle this problem?  The below images illustrates my problem exactly.  The play button gets scaled down from the Nexus 10 to the new Nexus 7 while the bearded guy gets scaled up so that it remains as the same physical size on both devices.  My images are currently doing what the bearded guy image is doing but I would like it to do what the play/connect buttons do which is scale down on the New Nexus 7.
(top image = New Nexus 7
bottom image = Nexus 10)

[image: New Nexus 7]

[image: Nexus 10]

Comment: You can't. But check your layout, the size in which images appear is not fixed just because they are taken from xhdpi or mdpi.

Comment: Also even if you could, that would be the wrong choice, think about how many devices there are...

Comment: Yeah I know Android does some scaling which is what's messing me up I think.  The same image scales up on the new Nexus 7 so that it's physical size matches that of the Nexus 10 which is not want I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set a drawable folder for a specific device, and it's also impractical, since there are too many devices out there (see [**here**](http://opensignal.com/reports/fragmentation.php) for example).

However, if you are unhappy with the way android choose the buckets of which file to use for each device configuration, you can use your own algorithm. there are 2 options to where to put the files in this case:

1. put the image files in res/drawable-nodpi (or res/raw) . for each image add a suffix/prefix to show which configuration it's used for.
2. put the image files in assets . this is a more flexible method, since you can even create sub folders and any file name you wish.

in both methods, you should also use your own image-sampling method , depending on your own rules.

Comment: Thanks but this method wouldn't allow me to layout my images in the graphical interface or the xml since I would have to assign the sources in the code.

Comment: I don't understand. you are unhappy with how android gets you the image, so you can always make your own rules, and i've just provided you with 2 ways to achieve it. of course, since you make your own rules, you have to decide how to scale the images.

Comment: Also - not all images scale very well although I guess I could use the 9-slice approach help scale them correctly.

Comment: Your method would work perfectly if I didn't want to use the different drawable folders and do my work in code.

Comment: using the drawable folders means that you agree to use the method that android manages the resources, so you have to follow its rules. if you don't want to follow its rules, you can use any of the methods i've written. and again, it's really not recommended to specify resources per device.

Comment: That's a pretty outdated source. Many device makers have rolled back a lot of the unusual resolutions. Samsungs Note had an unusual size, but the Note 2 ended up the same res as the S3. While the screens may be different sizes, they're trying to keep consistent resolutions (except that Nexus 4 guy).

Comment: @radley i don't understand what you are talking about and to what sentence you are referring ...

Answer (score 2):

In order to keep using the drawable resource folders, I had to do the following to differentiate the Nexus 7 2013 and the Nexus 10 since they both would use the xhdpi folder by default:

For the Nexus 7 I ended up using: drawable-sw600dp-xhdpi

For the Nexus 10 I ended up using: drawable-sw720dp-xhdpi

I had 2 sets of assets scaled differently in each folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the size and then scale the image to the required size based on the size of the display.

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();    
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);    
    int screenDensity = metrics.densityDpi;
```

Comment: I would like to avoid doing this in the code as using the graphical xml interface is a better method to do layouts.

Comment: Fine, but that means multiple copies of various images to create and maintain which is not necessarily a good solution either.

Comment: I thought multiple copies of the same image(scaled differently) is what most apps do.. why else would they have the multiple drawable directories for each screen density class?

Comment: Your answer combined with @android developer's answer seemed to work alright if I do my scaling in code.. thanks!